# Android Studio Projects with PepperSDK not working after Android Studio Version Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 1

Tags: android-studio, pepper

In our Team Problems arrised with opening android Studio Projekt after we upgraded our Android Studio to version Giraffe 2022.3.1. After disableling the plugin everything worked again.

After downgrading our Android Studio back to Flamingo 2022.2.1 it worked again. The plugin might be depricated as Pepper is from 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in is barely maintained.
The APIs work fine without it.
I don't use it anymore.

You can connect to the robot's tablet using `adb connect <tablet_ip>`.

To get started on an app, I'm usually starting from [the code of the tutorials](https://github.com/aldebaran/qisdk-tutorials).

If you can find more recent open source apps, it may help you skip the amount of gradle and Android SDK updates required.
For instance [I have this app around](https://gitlab.com/victor.paleologue/epistemic-planning-tell-pepper).